# about facebook apprequest message

Tags: facebook, request, message

```
FB.ui( {
    method: 'apprequests',
    message: "hi, come and play with me.",
    filters: ['app_non_users'],
    frictionlessRequests : true,
    to: toids.join(',')
},
function(response) {
```

When I click and the request window opened, I can see the message is correct.
But the one who receive my request shows that **"xx sent you a request."**
Is it something wrong?
Or it will be showed in anything else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add a parameter `new_style_message:true` , which works sometime. I mean notification goes like `hi, come and play with me`. so then your apprequest function will be like:

```
FB.ui( {
    method: 'apprequests',
    message: "hi, come and play with me.",
    filters: ['app_non_users'],
    frictionlessRequests : true,
    to: toids.join(','),
    new_style_message:true
},
function(response) {
```

though i'll say don't rely on it since it's an undocumented parameter. btw I too use it anyway

Comment: Hi, do you have a screenshot of what new_style_message:true does?